# Control is not updated after calling its invoke method

Tags: c#, multithreading

**EDITED and asking for re-open**

my question has been put on hold as it was considered off-topic and I did not add any source code. In my opinion, there was no need to add source code, as I wrote a simple question which could have been answered without any source code: *"Now, my assumption is that the thread is terminated and because of this, the invoke is not called anymore. Does that xound sensible?"* This question has been answered and I learned that this is not the reason. At that time it made sense to add some source code. I think that now the question should meet the requirements you require (though I still think that this was not the case at the beginning :-)) Anyway, could you please re-open this question?

**End asking for re-open**

I have a C# program where I want to update two controls from another thread.
The first update is working pretty fine. The text is shown as it's intended. But the second text box is not filled anymore. The second invoke is called quite at the "end" of the thread.

It is filled though if I add an `MessageBox.Show("...")` after the invoke call.
Now, my assumption is that the thread is terminated and because of this, the invoke is not called anymore.
Does that sound sensible?
What can I do to make the textbox update even at the end of the thread?

Here's the code (or: parts of it)

The task is called after a button is pressed:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\iperf3.exe",
                Arguments = "[...]",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            }
        };
        proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorHandler);
        proc.Exited += new EventHandler(ExitHandler);
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }
```

After the process is finished, it calls the ExitHandler method (which in turn starts a new process:

```
    private void ExitHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        proc.CancelErrorRead();
        proc.CancelOutputRead();
        proc.Dispose();
        proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\iperf3.exe",
                Arguments = "[...]",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            }
        };
        proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler2);
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorHandler);
        proc.Exited += new EventHandler(ExitHandler2);
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }
```

After the 2nd thread finished, the following method is launched:

```
    private void ExitHandler2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Command exited.", "Information"); // When commenting this line, labl2 is not filled anymore, see below /*****/
        proc.CancelErrorRead();
        proc.CancelOutputRead();
        button1.Invoke(new Action(() => button1.Enabled = true));
        proc.Dispose();
    }
```

The updates of the text boxes are made by parsing the output of the processes. These are received by the OutputHandler methods:

For first task:

```
    void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        ...
        label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = "[some captured text]")); // This part is always working
        ...
    }
```

and similarly for the second task:

```
    void OutputHandler2(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        ...
        label2.Invoke(new Action(() => label2.Text = "[some captured text]"));  // This one is only working when showing a MessagBox on ExitHandler2
    }
```

The text in label2 is only shown if the MessageBox.Show command is executed (marked with /*****/)

**Solution**
As i cannot add this as the answer of the question, I add that here. Maybe it is helpful for someone.
After several days of trying different changes to the code, I found out that the `proc.CancelOutputRead();` instruction is preventing the form from updating. It seems that the output has not yet been fully parsed at the time the reading of the output is stopped. When removing this instruction (as well as the `proc.Dispose()` instructions, the values are shown correctly.
The `proc.Dispose()` calls are then made in the `onClosing` event handler of the main form.
Thanks for your support!

Comment: being "at the end of the thread" should not make any difference.
Invoke is called synchronously, meaning your code will wait until it's completed. I think you have a different problem in your code. Post it!

Comment: Now as you say it... I'll modify that. (I took snippets from the Internet and didn't think too much about whether that makes sense or not.) Probably, there's no requirement for a `Process` ... If you write this as answer, I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I need to create a new process, as I'm running a console application which is definitely a new process. Of course, I could create a separate thread and then launch the console app in that thread, but this will also create a separate process, so there's no need to also create new thread if a new process is created anyway. I think that saves resources and makes things clearer.